# DB2 - create table throws syntax error "(" unexpected

Tags: db2, create-table

When I try to create table in db2, it throws the following error

```
$ db2 CREATE TABLE employee(emp_id INT NOT NULL, emp_name VARCHAR(100))
sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

The problem is not DB2 but the shell.  Use:

```
$ db2 "CREATE TABLE employee(emp_id INT NOT NULL, emp_name VARCHAR(100))"
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you should use $db2 to enter interactive mode and next enter your statement without db2 or enter your statement as below:

```
$ db2 "CREATE TABLE employee(emp_id INT NOT NULL, emp_name VARCHAR(100))"
```

Generally, you need to use double quotes `"` as below:

```
$ db2 "insert ...."
$ db2 "delete ...."
...
```